# Mapbox GL JS set color on the specific searched address

Tags: jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am looking for a way to paint a specific address when searched on map. I cannot find a way around. I tried Mapbox Studio but could not find this specific feature. I am attaching a reference image. Any help will be appreciated.
[Checkout this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWHYd.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the feature of draw polygon.
You can refer to these examples for more information:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/
and
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/

Comment: This is much appreciated. Just one more question do you have any idea how to get coordinates of the search address from MapboxGeocoder. It will be done then

Comment: I am able to get coordinates with geocoder of searched address. But this geojson-polygon requires outline coordinates to fill the color. How can I get these outline coordinates with address' coordinate?